# Nestable List Plugin PHP MYSQlL Json Tree structure

Tags: php, mysql, json, list

my first question. I am using **Nestable List Plugin** and trying to get same structure from an database.

The database looks like this (data source)
(tobad need 10 reputation)
This type of structure

ID: 1
ParentID: 0
Text: Hello World
Type: Text
----New row
ID: 2
ParentID: 1
Text: CHild :D
Type: text

and so on., dont know the name for it but thats one type of hierarchy structure.
I am trying to convert that into something like this, with unlimited lvls:
[{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15,"children":[{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18}]}]

This is my try so far

PHP Side

```
if($productSQL[0])
{  
    foreach($productSQL[1]['obj_ID'] as $iIDKey => $iIDValues) 
    { 

        if($productSQL[1]['objProductIDArr'][$iIDKey] == 0)
        {
            // Type Text
            $objData = $getDataInspection->listTemplate((object) ['resellerID' => $calcObj['resellerID'],'action' => 'objectByID','objectID' => $productSQL[1]['ii_object_id'][$iIDKey]]);
            $type = "text";

           // Push values into arrays
           array_push($idArr, $productSQL[1]['obj_ID'][$iIDKey]);
           array_push($textArr, $objData[0]['Value'][0]);
           array_push($contentType, $type);
           array_push($parentIDArr, $productSQL[1]['obj_parentID'][$iIDKey]);   

        }
        else
        {
            // Type Table
            $type = "table";
        }

    }

    $jsonHolder['id'] = $idArr;
    $jsonHolder['text'] = $textArr;
    $jsonHolder['parentID'] = $parentIDArr;
    $jsonHolder['type'] = $contentType;       

    $test = $functions->buildTree($jsonHolder);

    print_r($test);
}
else
{
    // No data present
    $json = "empty";
}
```

Save them into arrays and the save them into single array again
and then putting it further to buldTree function that I tried to implement from Veerendra but without succsess
[PHP - How to build tree structure list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384548/php-how-to-build-tree-structure-list)

Function

```
// Got this function from Stackoverflow :), thanks Veerendra :=
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach($elements['id'] as $elementsKey => $elementValues) 
    {        
        if ($elements['parentID'][$elementsKey] == $parentId) 
        {

            $jsonArr['id'] = $elementValues;  
            $jsonArr['parentID'] = $elements['parentID'][$elementsKey];  
            $jsonArr['text'] = $elements['text'][$elementsKey];  
            $jsonArr['type'] = $elements['type'][$elementsKey]; 

            $children = $this->buildTree($elements, $elementValues);
            if ($children) 
            {
                $elements['children'] = $jsonArr;
            }

            $branch[] = $jsonArr;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

This is the result so far from $branch

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 219
            [parentID] => 0
            [text] => butik
            [type] => text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 244
            [parentID] => 0
            [text] => kontor
            [type] => text
        )

)
```

Hope this question makes any sence?, I can explain further afcorse, just ask. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it thanks to --> Pierre de LESPINAY
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22020668/1912618

```
if($productSQL[0])
{  
    foreach($productSQL[1]['obj_ID'] as $iIDKey => $iIDValues) 
    { 
        if($productSQL[1]['objProductIDArr'][$iIDKey] == 0)
        {
            // Type Text
            $objData = $getDataInspection->listTemplate((object) ['resellerID' => $calcObj['resellerID'],'action' => 'objectByID','objectID' => $productSQL[1]['ii_object_id'][$iIDKey]]);
            $type = "text";
            $arr[] = ['id' => $productSQL[1]['obj_ID'][$iIDKey], 'parentid' => $productSQL[1]['obj_parentID'][$iIDKey], 'name' => $objData[0]['Value'][0]];
        }
        else
        {
            // Type Table
            $type = "table";

        }
    }
    $tree = $functions->createTree($arr);
    print_r($tree);
}
else
{
    // No data present
    $json = "empty";
}


// Class
    /* Recursive branch extrusion */
    function createBranch(&$parents, $children) {
        $tree = array();
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if (isset($parents[$child['id']])) {
                $child['children'] =
                    $this->createBranch($parents, $parents[$child['id']]);
            }
            $tree[] = $child;
        } 
        return $tree;
    }

    /* Initialization */
    function createTree($flat, $root = 0) {
        $parents = array();
        foreach ($flat as $a) {
            $parents[$a['parentid']][] = $a;
        }
        return $this->createBranch($parents, $parents[$root]);
    }
```

This code give me solution to create unlimited lvls and unlimited parents that works Nestable List Plugin. To create an JSON from the array
use `json_encode($tree,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

:)