# Generate correct data in select tag

Tags: php, select, recursion, tree, parentid

Structure of the table **category**:

```
id | parent_id | name
----------------------
1  | NULL      | test1
2  | NULL      | test2
3  | 1         | test3
4  | 1         | test4
5  | 3         | test5
6  | 2         | test6
7  | 6         | test7
8  | 3         | test8
```

It is tree.

So, this is what I want in PHP:
I have id (it can be function argument), for example 5 and I want generate select tags, (in this example 3 level) so I want generate something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lh8y2mzh/

`test6` and `test7` are not in select and this is what I want. It should work recursively I think. Any help? How to make the function?

Comment: Seems to be a homework!!!

Comment: I just have no idea how to solve the problem.I find only how to generate tree from data but I can't adjust it like above

Comment: Check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384548/php-how-to-build-tree-structure-list

Comment: Ravi Hirani thanks but it return all elements from table