# How to build dinamically a multilevel category with PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Lets assume I have a table like this:

```
-> id | parent_id | name 
-> 1  | 0         | Food
-> 2  | 1         | Salty
-> 3  | 1         | Sweet
-> 4  | 2         | Patty
-> 5  | 4         | Meat
-> 6  | 3         | Cupcake
-> 7  | 5         | Made on Oven
-> 8  | 5         | Fried
-> 9  | 6         | Chocolate
```

I wonder what kind of witchcraft i have to make in PHP to get an ordered result *dinamically without knowing the ammount of sublevels that the list are going to have* like this:

```
Food
- Salty
- - Patty
- - - Meat
- - - - Made on Oven
- - - - Fried
- Sweet 
- - Cupcake
- - - Chocolate
```

Thank you!

Comment: Run a query where `parent_id` equals 0 to get all the top-level categories. Iterate over the results and get all the records with that `parent_id`. Rinse-and-repeat

Comment: Have you tried something already that isn't working?

Comment: I can build 2 levels, Main Categories, and one subcategories. But i dont know how to build all the possible subcategories dinamically.

Comment: Solved with this script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384548/php-how-to-build-tree-structure-list